# Placing circles or any shape over an image at specified location

Tags: android, imageview

I want to draw circles or other shapes over an images at specified Coordinates in android in java. Please help me out.

Comment: post your code and specify where you are facing problem.

Comment: provide some more information.

Comment: I have one image and from services i got one set of coordinate. i want to write some text on that specific coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom xml for circle shape. Now place an imageview in your activity layout and don't pass the src in that. In your activity class as soon as you get the coordinates, do these two things

```
imageView.setX(value) and imageView.setY(value)
finally pass your custom xml to imageView.setImageResource
```

Hope this helps !!